# How to filter data in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data set like `d1`.

```
import pandas as pd
d1 = {
'customers': pd.Series([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4]),
'channel': pd.Series(['a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c']),
'freq': pd.Series([3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2])
}
d1=pd.DataFrame(d1)
```

I want to get list of customers who have used only two distinct channels and channels 'a' is mandatory.

For ex.. 1st customer has used two distinct channels 'a'& 'b'
2nd customer had used 'a' & 'c' 3rd customer used 'a' & 'b'. But customer 4 has not used channel 'a' and so on....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want ?

```
d1[d1.customers.isin(d1[(d1.freq==2) & (d1.channel=="a")].customers)]

  channel  customers  freq
3       c          2     2
4       a          2     2
5       a          3     2
6       b          3     2
```

HTH

Comment: No. freq=2 means, that customers will have two records. In those two records at least one record should be in channel 'a'.

Comment: That is not what your dataframe contains though.

Comment: I don't get it. There is no column "record". Please rephrase your question, and post a more precise output of what you want. (And correct the input if needed)

Comment: look at customer 2, he have two records.In these two records, first record from channel 'c' and second record from channel 'a'. I want these kind of customers in my output. Look at customer 3, he has same pattern like customer 2.

Comment: @kondal, please revise your question

Comment: @kondal I edited, but i'm still not sure if I understand well